# Cannot add as subview, have to add to content view swift 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to add a view on top of the current rootviewcontroller and I'm doing this in a separate class. But the issue is that when I upgraded to swift 4 I was getting this error. "Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view itself, instead add them to the -contentView." "Here is the code. Self in [current.view addSubview:self]; is the current view.""

```
- (void)show
{
    UIViewController *current = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (current.presentedViewController) {
        current = current.presentedViewController;
    }
    [current.view addSubview:self];
}
```

Comment: Why are you talking about Swift? This is Objective-C code.

Comment: sorry I meant objectivec